# Threejs partially applied texture

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to do a partially applied texture with shaders on a teapot in ThreeJS. Currently it looks like this: [image]

I need it to look like this: [image]

But I'm not sure how I should approach this, do I do that clipping with shader itself, or threejs code? I can't figgure out the basic idea of how to do this.

Comment: When asking a homework question, you are requested to say it is a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment shader (it would have been nice if you posted it) you can do something like:

```
if( vUv.y > 0.4 && vUv.y < 0.6 )
    gl_FragColor = vec4( texture_color, 1.0 );
else
    gl_FragColor = vec4( background_color, 1.0 );
```

Take a look at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bpatofd4/